# sendSynchronousRequest fails under 3.1.2 after "Don't Allow" location fetch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

I'm having a problem with doing a `sendSynchronousRequest` failing. It only fails after I try to get the current geolocation and the user hits "Don't Allow". And it only happens under 3.1.2. (As far as I can tell. It works fine in 3.0.1.)

Here's what I do:

I set up a very basic test app, that has almost nothing in it. In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I add a call to my function, test, which is here:

```
- (void) test
{
 CLLocationManager *mLM;

 mLM = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 mLM.delegate = self;

 if ( [mLM locationServicesEnabled] )
 {
  [mLM startUpdatingLocation];
 }
}
```

My delegate methods are pretty simple too:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
 [self sendRequest]; // succeeds
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
 [self sendRequest]; // fails
}
```

Finally, here's my sendRequest:

```
- (void) sendRequest
{
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://theurl"]];  // this is actually a valid URL, changed here for privacy
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
 [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];

 NSString    *unpw   = @"username:password";
 NSString    *base64 = [NSString base64StringFromString:unpw];
 [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

 NSURLResponse *response = nil;
 NSError    *error = nil;
 NSData    *respdata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

 [request release];
}
```

The call to `sendSynchronousRequest` hangs. This has been very frustrating. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could the URL you're GETing be having network troubles? Does the call hang indefinitely?

Comment: If the user allows the geolocation fetch, sendSynchronousRequest succeeds just fine. It's always worked just fine everywhere else, except now after when the user says "Don't Allow" to a geolocation fetch in 3.1.2.

It seems to hang indefinitely, though I haven't waiting around for more than a couple minutes to find out.

Comment: As a datapoint, try running sendRequest in its own thread (just use NSInvocationOperation).

Comment: Not knowing how to use NSInvocationOperation, I tried using performSelectorInBackground instead, and it seemed to work. Though that doesn't help me too much as I still would like to solve the original problem. Interesting to note, though.

Comment: Oops. Accidentally upvoted that comment. Can you post a stack trace from sendRequest in both the passing and failing cases? My thought is that the app might be in some modal runloop when your delegate methods get called that keeps the network connection from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work it's magic. Make sure the mLm is your class varialble, so you can to this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [self.mLm release];
 self.mLM = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 self.mLM.delegate = nil;

 [self sendRequest]; // fails - This time it will work!!!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it almost fixed it, but not quite. The sendRequest succeeded, but I got a fail later on. But I played around a bit, and found a small variation of your code that works:
 
 [mLM stopUpdatingLocation];
 mLM.delegate = nil;
 [mLM release];
 mLM = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 mLM.delegate = self;